# PDFSharp.Xamarin.Forms: add image to PDF from Resource

Tags: image, xamarin.forms, pdfsharp

I have a Xamarin.Forms app for Android and iOS, where I use PDFSharp.Xamarin.Forms to create a PDF-file and put some text on this with color. This file never gets saved on the phone, since it will only E-mail the file (with System.Net.Mail). This all works, but I have difficulties with the following:

I have an image (for Android in /Resources/drawable/image.jpg and for iOS in /Resources/image.jpg) which I want to add to the PDF-file. I Googled some examples, but nothing worked for me so far.

Is it even possible to do this? If so, how?

Hope someone can help.

Comment: instead of saying "nothing worked", show us what you actually tried and describe the specific problem you encountered.  The PDFSharp docs have several examples of using images: http://www.pdfsharp.net/wiki/Graphics-sample.ashx?AspxAutoDetectCookieSupport=1#Images_35

Comment: I already used the link you just send here. Problem is that all those example use the path of my desktop to get the image, nothing shows a way to get the image from a platform specific Resource folder.

Comment: XImage has a FromStream() method, I would try that

Comment: I tried this: ResourceManager rm = new ResourceManager("AppResources", typeof(PDFModel).Assembly);
            XImage im = XImage.FromStream(rm.GetStream("image.jpg")); But that gives the error: cannot convert from 'System.IO.UnmanagedMemoryStream' to 'System.Func<System.IO.Stream>'

Comment: there are numerous examples of loading resources as streams in Xamarin

Comment: Now I tried to use this: var assembly = IntrospectionExtensions.GetTypeInfo(typeof(PDFModel)).Assembly;
            Stream stream = assembly.GetManifestResourceStream("image.jpg");
            XImage im = XImage.FromStream(stream); I got the following error: cannot convert from 'System.IO.Stream' to 'System.Func<System.IO.Stream>, any solution for this?

Comment: `ImageSource.FromStream(() => new MemoryStream(stream));`

Comment: Doesn't work. Cannot Convert Stream to byte[]

Comment: Okay so now I use XImage im = XImage.FromStream(() => stream);
gfx.DrawImage(im, 0, 0, 250, 140); , but the app crashed on the last line because: System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.' gfx comes from 'XGraphics gfx = XGraphics.FromPdfPage(page);' and I use gfx through the entire code, so I don't think the problems is there. Any ideas?

Comment: then `im` must be null

Comment: Like this? XImage im = null;
                im = XImage.FromStream(() => stream);
                gfx.DrawImage(im, 0, 0, 250, 140); Because that gives me the same error.

Comment: if `im` is null then `XImage.FromStream()` is returning null, you need to figure out why

Comment: My stream has a length (non-zero), so the stream cannot be null. The image (im) has a size (width and height), also non-zero, so that should also be okay.

Comment: I included this: 
                if (stream == null)
                    throw new ArgumentException("No resource with name " + name); , but the exception never gets thrown. So the stream is not null.